# I got an error with sdl2 ttf and emscripten

Tags: c++, sdl-2, truetype, emscripten, sdl-ttf

i was porting my game to emscripten. Everything was fine until SDL_ttf.
Actually i am using sdl2 + sdl2 image + sdl mixer.

I will show an example:

```
SDL_Color color = {255,255,255};
    std::cout << "1\n";
    font = TTF_OpenFont("saucery/font/font1.otf", 8);
    if (!font)
        printf("Unable to load font: %s \n",  TTF_GetError());
    std::cout << "2\n";
    SDL_Surface *surf = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,"Oieee",color);
    std::cout << "3\n";
    if (surf){
        std::cout << (int)surf << "\n";
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Game::instance->GetRenderer(),surf);
        std::cout << "4\n";
        Uint32 format;
        int acess,w,h;
        SDL_QueryTexture(texture, &format,&acess,&w,&h);
        dimensions2.x = 0;
        dimensions2.y = 0;
        dimensions2.h = h;
        dimensions2.w = w;

        SDL_FreeSurface(surf);


    }
```

In this code i just open an font (i have already changed the size and the type to .ttf). Everything seems to run fine until:

```
SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface
```

I put some std::cout to see where the code was "crashing". Everytime it calls the createTextureFrom on the console shows to me "45" and the running stops there.

Even with any std::cout i still get this error.
this is driving me crazy already ._.

Comment: you could try adding a check to TTF get error just to be sure, just after `3`? Truth is that this might have to do with your opengl setup. WebGL is a lot more restrictive than desktop opengl, maybe you got lucky up to this point.

Comment: Actually there is no error.
I got a response form emscripten developer. he said that there is no port for sdl2_ttf yet. i am using sdl2 + sdlttf (1).

That's the reason. there is a seg fault at SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface

Comment: yeah so in my emscripten project I have just been using freetype, which I brought in tree, it seems to work great. but i'm not actually using SDL image or any of that, i'm just using opengl directly.